# How to get dynamic array's size in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to get size of **dynamic array** in C with **sizeof**.
I have structure and and make it array with 10 elements.

```
struct date{
int day;
int month;
int year;
};

void main(){
struct date *table;

table = (struct date*) malloc(sizeof(struct date) * 10);
}
```

So when I try to get size with sizeof I get 8 instead of 120 (since size of structure is 12).

```
printf("%d, sizeof(table)); 
output is 8
```

Instead of making it dynamic array i changed it to static array to see what happens and it gave 120. So I don't understand what is the problem. I know I cannot say sizeof(*table) because it will give size of first element. For the context purposes need to use dynamic array for expanding it's size for every new data.

Comment: A `sizeof` expression is evaluated during compilation time. It gives you the size of the type of the operand. In the case of a dynamic array, it gives you the size of a pointer, which is typically 4 or 8 bytes (depending on the underlying platform).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example `table` has type `struct date *`.  So when you use the `sizeof` operator on it you get the size of the pointer.

There is no portable way to determine how much available space a pointer to allocated memory points to.  You need to keep track of that yourself.

Comment: will this apply to passing static arrays to functions? just for an example, if I have static array of struct date array[10] and want to print size of the array in another function, printSize(struct date a[]), will this case happen?

Comment: @kimboi Arrays are converted to a pointer to their first element when passed to a function, so you would also get the size of a pointer in that case.  You would need to pass the size to the function in a separate parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to store the size information somewhere like in this example:

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    int arr[];
}int_array_t;

int_array_t *alloc(size_t nelem)
{
    int_array_t *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) + nelem * sizoef(arr -> arr[0]));

    if(arr)
    {
        arr -> size = nelem;
    }
    return arr;
}
```