# Determine the length of a dynamic array after creation time in C

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
size_t val = sizeof(p)/sizeof(int);

printf("this array (p) can content %lu elements \n",val);
```

Hi everyone,

1. I've been trying to make this program print "this array (P) can content 10 elements". But it doesn't work. ( for me, the value of val is suppose to be the length of this array. size of total elements of p divided by one element of p)
2. and when i try to print the sizeof(p) after malloc, it's not equal to 4*10 (40);

May someone tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: the sizeof trick only works for static arrays, you have to remember the size yourself. It doesnt work because p is a pointer, its always 4 or 8 bytes depending on your platform

Comment: @pm100 can you please help me with a little program wich give the length of a dynamic array at a time ?

Comment: size is n*sizeof(int) .  sizeof(p) never changes.  It is not doing what you think it is

Comment: Multiply it by n

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get dynamic array's size in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65270361/how-to-get-dynamic-arrays-size-in-c)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about elementary material that should be learned by reading a C primer or textbook and working on course assignments rather than by asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` is a pointer, `sizeof(p)` is not the size of the array that was allocated by `malloc()`, it is just the size of the pointer itself, which may be 4 or 8 depending on the platform (among other more exotic possibilities).

The expression `sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])` only works for arrays, defined as `int a[10];` or possibly with a length determined at compile time from the intializer: `int a[] = { 0, 2, 4 };`.

There is no portable way to retrieve the size of the block allocated by `malloc()` from the pointer. You must keep track of the size separately.

Comment: Upvoted. For anyone wondering, a pointer is `2` bytes on 8-bit microcontrollers such as ATmega328 (Arduino Uno, Nano, Mini), `4` bytes on most 32-bit architectures, and `8` bytes on most 64-bit architectures.

Comment: I provide an extension of this answer to demonstrate how to "keep track of the size separately" [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72653068/4561887).

Answer (score 1):

See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72653047/4561887), and the comments under the question. You must keep track of the size yourself. Here is a basic demo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    const size_t NUM_INTS = 10;
    
    int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*NUM_INTS);
    printf("p can hold %zu integers\n", NUM_INTS);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> p can hold 10 integers
> ```

### How to containerize a dynamically-allocated array in C

#### 1. Make an `array_int_t` "array of `int`s" container

Let's take it one step further and containerize it as an array of integers.

Container:

```c
/// A container represending a dynamically-allocated array of integers
typedef struct array_int_s
{
    /// Pointer to the first element in a dynamically-allocated array
    /// of ints
    int * start;

    /// Number of elements in the array
    size_t size;
} array_int_t;
```

Usage:

```
array_int_t array_int;
array_int.start = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*NUM_INTS);
array_int.size = NUM_INTS;
    
printf("array_int can hold %zu integers\n", array_int.size);
```

#### 2. Add an `array_int_create()` constructor or "factory" function to create an array of `int`s

And one step further:

Add a create function:

```c
/// Dynamically create and return an array of `num_elements` of type `int`.
array_int_t array_int_create(size_t num_elements)
{
    array_int_t dynamic_array = 
    {
        .start = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*num_elements),
        .size = num_elements,
    };
    
    return dynamic_array;
}
```

And use it:

```c
array_int_t array_int2 = array_int_create(NUM_INTS);
printf("array_int2 can hold %zu integers\n", array_int2.size);
```

#### 3. [BEST] Update the `array_of_int_create()` "factory" function to fully dynamically allocate an array container plus the array space, and return a ptr to the container

BUT, that factory function above technically isn't quite right, as it's not fully dynamically allocated. Rather, it requires each `array_int_t` to be statically allocated, and then it simply dynamically allocates the memory for the array only, but not the container itself. We actually need to dynamically allocate both the container and the array memory, so let's fix that.

Here is a full and robust example, with detailed comments. I may have changed some of the variable names in this example.

From **[containers_array_dynamic_array_of_int_with_factory_create_func.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/containers_array_dynamic_array_of_int_with_factory_create_func.c)** in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> // `memset()`


/// A container representing a dynamically-allocated array of integers
typedef struct array_of_int_s
{
    /// Pointer to the first element in a dynamically-allocated array
    /// of ints
    int * data;

    /// Number of elements in the array
    size_t size;
} array_of_int_t;

/// "Zero", or "clear", an array by setting all of its data elements to zero!
void array_of_int_zero(array_of_int_t* array_of_int)
{
    if (array_of_int == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: null ptr\n");
        return;
    }

    // debugging; sample output: 40
    // printf("array_of_int->size*sizeof(array_of_int->data[0]) = %zu\n",
    //     array_of_int->size*sizeof(array_of_int->data[0]));

    memset(&array_of_int->data[0], 0,
        array_of_int->size*sizeof(array_of_int->data[0]));
}

/// A "factory" function to dynamically create and return a ptr to a
/// dynamically-allocated object containing an array of `num_elements` of type
/// `int`.
///
/// The data in the array is zeroed by this function.
///
/// See also this answer which helped me to some extent:
///     https://stackoverflow.com/a/65270682/4561887
/// and my answer where I shared this code:
///     https://stackoverflow.com/a/72653068/4561887
///
/// Returns NULL if malloc() fails due to "out of memory".
array_of_int_t* array_of_int_create(size_t num_elements)
{
    // Allocate memory for the entire struct, as well as the actual array space
    // that the `.data` member will point to, which will be located just
    // **after** the `array_of_int_t` object.
    // - Note: `sizeof(*(array_of_int->data))` is the equivalent to `sizeof
    //   (int)` in this case, except that it's more robust because if you
    //   change the `data` type in the `array_of_int_t` struct from `int*` to
    //   something else, you do NOT also have to change this `malloc()` call
    //   here!. It could also be written like this:
    //   `sizeof(array_of_int->data[0])`.
    //
    // // debugging; is 56 bytes
    // size_t num_bytes = sizeof(array_of_int_t) + num_elements*sizeof(int);
    // printf("num_bytes = %zu\n", num_bytes);
    array_of_int_t *array_of_int = (array_of_int_t*)malloc(sizeof(*array_of_int)
        + num_elements*sizeof(*(array_of_int->data)));

    if (array_of_int == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: out of memory\n");
        return array_of_int;
    }

    // Set the array data to point to the first byte just past the end of the
    // `array_of_int_t` struct, which data has also been `malloc`ed just above
    // for exactly this purpose. Note that in "pointer arithmetic", doing
    // `array_of_int + 1` jumps one "element" forward, where "element" is one
    // entire `array_of_int_t` struct. Therefore, that jumps forward to point
    // to the first byte **after** the `array_of_int` object.
    //
    // I then cast it to an `int*` to point the `->data` member to it. I could
    // also cast it to a `void*` to make this code generic if I wanted, but
    // casting to `void*` can also be more error-prone because it makes the
    // compiler no longer verify the pointer type of the variable being
    // assigned, since **any** pointer can point to a `void*` type. So, I'll
    // avoid casting to `void*` here.
    array_of_int->data = (int*)(array_of_int + 1);

    array_of_int->size = num_elements;
    array_of_int_zero(array_of_int);

    return array_of_int;
}

/// Print all elements in an array
void array_of_int_print(const array_of_int_t* array_of_int)
{
    if (array_of_int == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: null ptr\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("array data: {");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array_of_int->size; i++)
    {
        printf("%i", array_of_int->data[i]);
        if (i < array_of_int->size - 1)
        {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf("}\n");
}

int main()
{
    const size_t NUM_INTS = 10;


    // 1. Basic demo

    int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*NUM_INTS);
    printf("p can hold %zu integers\n", NUM_INTS);

    // write some data to this array
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_INTS; i++)
    {
        p[i] = i;
    }

    // print the data out now
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_INTS; i++)
    {
        printf("p[%zu] = %i\n", i, p[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");


    // 2. Containerized demo

    array_of_int_t array_of_int;
    // Note: `sizeof(array_of_int->data[0])` is the same as `sizeof(int)` in
    // this case, except it is more-robust since it doesn't require changing
    // the code here if you ever change the type of `.data` from `int*` to
    // something else.
    //
    // // debugging: is 40 bytes
    // size_t num_bytes = sizeof(array_of_int.data[0])*NUM_INTS;
    // printf("num_bytes = %zu\n", num_bytes);
    array_of_int.data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(array_of_int.data[0])*NUM_INTS);
    array_of_int.size = NUM_INTS;
    printf("array_of_int_t can hold %zu integers\n", array_of_int.size);

    // write all zeros to this array, then write a few values, then print the
    // whole array
    array_of_int_zero(&array_of_int);
    array_of_int.data[2] = 123;
    array_of_int.data[7] = 456789;
    array_of_int_print(&array_of_int);
    printf("\n");


    // 3. [BEST!] A fully containerized demo, with a factory "create" function
    // to dynamically make an array object! Also, with full error checking to
    // ensure `malloc()` actually worked!

    array_of_int_t * array_of_int2 = array_of_int_create(NUM_INTS);
    if (array_of_int2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: array_of_int_create() failed (out of memory)!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("array_of_int2 can hold %zu integers\n", array_of_int2->size);
    // the `array_of_int_create()` function already zeroed all the data, so
    // let's just write in some values then print out the whole array!
    array_of_int2->data[1] = 1;
    array_of_int2->data[5] = 5;
    array_of_int2->data[9] = 9;
    array_of_int_print(array_of_int2);
    printf("\n");


    return 0;
}
```

**Sample output:**

```
eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=gnu17 containers_array_dynamic_array_of_int_with_factory_create_func.c -o bin/a -lm && bin/a
p can hold 10 integers
p[0] = 0
p[1] = 1
p[2] = 2
p[3] = 3
p[4] = 4
p[5] = 5
p[6] = 6
p[7] = 7
p[8] = 8
p[9] = 9

array_of_int_t can hold 10 integers
array data: {0, 0, 123, 0, 0, 0, 0, 456789, 0, 0}

array_of_int2 can hold 10 integers
array data: {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9}
```